# Как правильно вывести информацию из JSON в SQL

Tags: python, sql, json

У меня есть JSON файл с таким наполнением:

```
    [
{
    "country": "Aruba",
    "languages": [
        "Dutch",
        "English",
        "Papiamento",
        "Spanish"
    ]
},
{
    "country": "Afghanistan",
    "languages": [
        "Balochi",
        "Dari",
        "Pashto",
        "Turkmenian",
        "Uzbek"
    ]
},
```

Я хочу перенести данные из этого файла в SQL таким кодом.

```
    import sqlite3
    import json


    with open('country-by-languages.json') as f:
        countries = json.load(f)

conn = sqlite3.connect("mytest.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE countries (Country varchar(3), Languages varchar(3))")

for country in countries:
    c.execute("insert into countries values (?, ?)",
              [country['country'], json.dumps(languages)])

        conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

И вроде бы все работает но вид в таблице получается не совсем тот который мне нужен а именно в столбике Languages я хочу видеть только сами языки а у меня выводится вообще вся информация о всех странах и так в каждой строке[image: мой скриншот результата].

Comment: А что у вас в переменной `languages`?? В данном коде она не описана, но похоже там тоже самое, что и в `countries`. А там должно быть `country['languages']` вместо этого.

Comment: Да спасибо вы правы.